# How to iterate over multiple elements of numericupdown

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I am new to c#,I have several numericupdown element that I want to use in a loop here is what I did,I also try several other things such as foreach.

```
private void AffecteValeurBinaire(int valeur)
        {
            nudBinaire3.Value = valeur % 2;
            valeur >>= 1;
            nudBinaire2.Value = valeur % 2;
            valeur >>= 1;
            nudBinaire1.Value = valeur % 2;
            valeur >>= 1;
            nudBinaire0.Value = valeur % 2;
        }
```

**i want to turn this code above which works into a loop and here is what i did above**

```
private NumericUpDown[] nudBinaire = new NumericUpDown[] {nudBinaire3,nudBinaire2,nudBinaire1,nudBinaire0 };
        private void AffecteValeurBinaire(int valeur)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i++)
            {
                nudBinaire[i].Value = valeur % 2;
                valeur >>= 1;
            }

        }
   

private void nudDecimal_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radDecimal.Checked)
        {
            nudHexadecimal.Value = nudDecimal.Value;
            AffecteValeurBinaire(Convert.ToInt32(nudDecimal.Value));
            Affiche7Segments(Convert.ToInt32(nudDecimal.Value));
        }

    }
    private void nudBinaire_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radBinaire.Checked)
        {
            decimal v = (nudBinaire0.Value * 8) + (nudBinaire1.Value * 4) +
            (nudBinaire2.Value * 2) + (nudBinaire3.Value);
            nudDecimal.Value = v;
            nudHexadecimal.Value = v;
            Affiche7Segments(Convert.ToInt32(nudDecimal.Value));
        }

    }
    private void nudHexadecimal_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radHexadecimal.Checked)
        {
            nudDecimal.Value = nudHexadecimal.Value;
            AffecteValeurBinaire(Convert.ToInt32(nudHexadecimal.Value));
            Affiche7Segments(Convert.ToInt32(nudDecimal.Value));
        }
    }
    
    private void radDecimal_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radDecimal.Checked == true)
        {
            nudDecimal.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    private void radBinaire_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           nudBinaire0.Enabled = nudBinaire1.Enabled = nudBinaire2.Enabled = nudBinaire3.Enabled = radBinaire.Checked;
    }

    private void radHexadecimal_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        nudHexadecimal.Enabled = radHexadecimal.Checked;
    }
```

** I receive this error:
a field initializer cannot refer to the field**

Comment: The for-loop looks quite problematic.  Starts at 3, goes to 4, and keeps going forever.

Comment: Shouldn't the loop like following?
for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                nudBinaire[i].Value = valeur % 2;
                valeur >>= 1;
            }

Comment: @Nantharupan , Yes I made a mistake but it doesn't work, these are objects created with the design of windows forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does not give the error :

```
    public class Test
    {
        static NumericUpDown nudBinaire0 = new NumericUpDown();
        static NumericUpDown nudBinaire1 = new NumericUpDown();
        static NumericUpDown nudBinaire2 = new NumericUpDown();
        static NumericUpDown nudBinaire3 = new NumericUpDown();

        //private void AffecteValeurBinaire(int valeur)
        //{
        //    nudBinaire3.Value = valeur % 2;
        //    valeur >>= 1;
        //    nudBinaire2.Value = valeur % 2;
        //    valeur >>= 1;
        //    nudBinaire1.Value = valeur % 2;
        //    valeur >>= 1;
        //    nudBinaire0.Value = valeur % 2;
        //}

        private NumericUpDown[] nudBinaire = new NumericUpDown[] { nudBinaire3, nudBinaire2, nudBinaire1, nudBinaire0 };
        private void AffecteValeurBinaire(int valeur)
        {
            for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i++)
            {
                nudBinaire[i].Value = valeur % 2;
                valeur >>= 1;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will try it but is it not going to modify the umeridupdown object that I created with window forms design

Comment: You create new objects when these objects already exist, I will modify my subject to add the functions of these objects

Comment: The items that I have as static is needed either in the form (which is declared in the designer.cs file) or added to your code.  The properties are need for your array object.

Answer (score 1):

The error text says that you cannot initialize a non static variable with another variable.

Hence, you cannot declare `nudBinaire` with the variables `nudBinaire3,nudBinaire2,nudBinaire1,nudBinaire0`. You **can** initialize it with global unknown variables. Like:

```
private NumericUpDown[] nudBinaire = new NumericUpDown[4];
```

and then declare it **inside** another function (like inside the void that contains the loop) with the `nudBinaire3,nudBinaire2,nudBinaire1,nudBinaire0` declared variables.

OR you can make both `nudBinaire` and `nudBinaire3,nudBinaire2,nudBinaire1,nudBinaire0` static variables.

Comment: Thanks but will it contain the objects of the numeriUpDown class that I created with the design of windows forms ?

Comment: you should declare an instance of `nudBinarie` inside a void, like the void that contains the loop

Comment: I have this error with this modification System.NullReferenceException : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Post the new code. or try @jdweng's answer (like I said also - make the variables static)

Comment: he create new objects when these objects already exist, I will modify my subject to add the functions of these objects

Comment: Let me tell you something important. In C# you create voids and variables that should only be called in one big void (which is usually inside the form.cs, like button_click or onLoad) as new instances,I mean,you create those voids like global functions **without specific values** inside them.Any specific values should be given in the big  to the new instances of those voids that you created in that big one void above, but **Not** where you create those voids (or variables). This is what `Object Oriented` is all about : you create a global object, and use it as a new instance inside other voids

Comment: All these objects of type numericUpDown are created in the Form1.Designer.cs file

Comment: But they are created separately because I created these different objects with the designer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to declare `nudBinaire` as a global variable, but initialize it in method (like `Form1_Load`).

```
// declare as a global variable
NumericUpDown[] nudBinaire;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // initialize nudBinaire
    nudBinaire = new NumericUpDown[] { nudBinaire3, nudBinaire2, nudBinaire1, nudBinaire0 };
}

private void AffecteValeurBinaire(int valeur)
{
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        nudBinaire[i].Value = valeur % 2;
        valeur >>= 1;
    }

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    // test
    AffecteValeurBinaire(100);
}
```